# p-fileupload doesn't work with lots of files

Tags: angular, primeng

We use

```
    <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="{{url}}" multiple="multiple"
                  (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)" (onError)="onError($event)" 
                  accept=".xml" maxFileSize="50000000">
    </p-fileUpload>
```

This works fine in most cases. But I have a use case where the user uploads 784 files with a total size of 1.02GB and a highest file size of 39MB.

The files are not sent and `OnError` is called.
But in the `OnError` no reason why it fails is provided:

```
private onError(event) {
    console.log("FileUpload.OnError:");
    console.log(event);
}
```

event.xhr.readyState is 4, event.xhr.response is empty.

When I upload the same files in smaller amounts it is working fine. So it seems the files are not the problem but the amount or the total size. But I'm not sure and I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Did you check your backend maximum request size?

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. I already had a max size of 1GB and I thought it was the size of the individual file but it is the size of all the files. I changed it to 2 GB and now the upload is continuing and is reaching my backend. 
It would be nice though if the error message of this component would said this is the problem.

Comment: great, I added the comment as a response for feature readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an error with your backend maximum request size.

Try to increase the maximum request size.